# Regex for containing alphanumeric but at least 2 letter consecutive and a number

Tags: python, regex

I need regex for containing alphanumeric but at least 2 letter consecutive and a number. Example:

```
123ab11 -> valid
11224 -> invalid
A1111u4 -> invalid
sb234d48 -> valid
skir1938s -> valid
282883 -> invalid
```

I tried `(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,15})$`, but this is not working.

Comment: Does it have to be regex? What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: Need to find sentences that contains those type of words.

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase your regex as:

```
^(?i)(?=.*\d)(?=.{6,15}$)[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z]{2}[A-Z0-9]*$
```

This pattern matches:

- `^` from the start of the input

  - `(?i)` case insensitive mode
  - `(?=.*\d)` lookahead and ensure that at least one digit be present
  - `(?=.{6,15}$)` length is 6 to 15 characters
  - `[A-Z0-9]*` match zero or more alphanumeric characters
  - `[A-Z]{2}` match 2 consecutive letters
  - `[A-Z0-9]*` match zero or more alphanumeric characters
- `$` end of the input

Answer (score 0):

You can assert a digit, and match 2 times a char A-Za-z

Using a case insensitive match using `re.IGNORECASE`

```
^(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[A-Z0-9]*?[A-Z]{2})[A-Z0-9]{6,15}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[A-Z]*[0-9])` Positive lookahead, assert at least a single digit
- `(?=[A-Z0-9]*?[A-Z]{2})` Positive lookahead, assert 2 consecutive chars A-Z
- `[A-Z0-9]{6,15}` Match 6-15 chars A-Za-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB8hOc/1)